# Powermock and mockito compatibility and changes

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I am trying to move to power mock 2.0.2 and mockito 2.0. 
Previously I used powermock to mock some local variables:
I used on test class

```
 @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
 @PrepareForTest({MyClass.class})
 whenNew(MyClass.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(myClassMock);
```

All is fine with Power mock 1.6..
When I tried to move to Powermock 2.x I can not find anymore the **whenNew()** method in PowerMock.
How this changed in the new Powermock?
Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And by the way which version of mockito is compatible wit Powermock? - i see there are some problems of support of Powermock with mockito

Comment: The `whenNew` method is still in the `PowerMockito` class. You probably have some issues with your dependencies. What is the mockito version you are trying to use? Afaik for 2.0 only beta versions exists and not all of them are supported by powermockito (check the [`wiki`](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito)).

Comment: I edited the post with dependencies. I am tring ro move to 2.x. I also I dont know if it is a good idea.

Comment: powermock 2.0.4 requires mockito 2.8.9+, give that combination a try

Comment: Strange i am trying now: powermock-api-mockito and powermock-module-junit4 version 2.0.4 and mockito-core 3.1.0. Still no whenNew method. Can you point me to a good example with the corect setup of PoerMock and mockito?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I missed the part where you defined the old api component, try `powermock-api-mockito2`.
 This is what I use in one of my projects (which defaults to `mockito-core 2.28.2`)

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Oh, yes moed from powermock 1 to 2 and i should change to powermock-api-mockito2. That was the problem, Thank you!

Comment: I had to also add powermock-core for testing static method's mock